Delete files from S3 bucket after completion of SingleStore Pipelines
I am currently running a Pipeline in SingleStore which takes a file from AWS S3 bucket, modifies the data as per business logic written in a stored procedure and then enters the records in a table.
How can I delete the file from AWS S3 bucket after the pipeline successfully completes?

Where are probably 10 different ways you can do it. Put as I haven't worked on SingelStore I can't tell the best way. But suggestion see if you can send some event back to AWS after the pipeline is done to run a lambda to delete the object.
Or maybe you can as soon you have fetch the file also move it to an folder there you have a lambda that triggers on put event and that lambda delete the file.

I thought of Lambda functions but I could not find any way to emit an event back to AWS.

I think you can check the information_schema.pipelines_files,batches,batches_summary table to ensure that all the records are processed and if you no longer require files in the s3 you can remove them afaik.
First, you can query the information_schema.PIPELINES_FILES view to see the status of files processed by the pipeline.
